# Develop in a non local environment

Tags: development-environment

I have set up a reactJS environment on digitalocean just to start learning developing with react and graphQL and i was wondering if there is a text editor that can connect to connect on the internet and retrieve the files of the project.

Im not really sure if something like this is doable but in my head is like i will code the files on the VPS with a proper text editor and save them so i can have some sort of live preview.

I have already tried with sublime and brackets but im not really sure how to connect them on the project folder in my vps.

Answer (score 0):

If your VPS has SFTP set up, you can use your SSH login details to connect and edit code live through an editor such as sublime text.

( I would recommend using FTP if the SSH access is through root or anything with authority on the server, if you do not care about security then feel free to use root )

https://www.sublimetext.com/

An SFTP / FTP plugin exists for what you require, please see below:

https://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp

**Example usage of the plugin is as follows**

1. Create a project folder
2. CTRL+SHIFT+P > "sftp" > SFTP -> Setup Server
3. Edit the login details within your sftp-config.json file
4. Make sure the remote path is correct and your credentials are correct
5. "upload on save" - change to true inside your sftp-config.json file
6. Save the sftp-config.json file, CTRL+SHIFT+P > "sftp" > SFTP Sync remote -> local

I'd recommend adding node_modules inside your ignore_regexes, as it can take up to 10-15 minutes to download these.

Now it should ( if set up correctly ) download the files specified in your "remote_path" folder. Saving future files will upload them to the server on save.

I hope this helps!